# Python Database Error

Tags: python, sqlite

When I put my database file (which is a .sdb) into a directory and try to access it from that directory, I receive an error. The error reads "unable to open database file". For example, let's say my .sdb file is in the "data" directory and I use the command "con = lite.connect('data\noktalar.sdb')", this error occurs. Why is that so?

Thanks.

Comment: I think, that is because you are using `\n` within that string which is geting interpreted as newline. Use raw-string and see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is the [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in python strings. You have to use double backslashes:

```
con = lite.connect('data\\noktalar.sdb')
```

Or like Senthil said, use raw strings:

```
con = lite.connect(r'data\noktalar.sdb')
```

For more information, check the Python doc about [string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

Where is your python process running from? Try to point to the absolute path of the file. And when pointing to path use raw string `r'c:\\mypath\data\notktalar.sub'`

Comment: Thanks. You solved my problem. Actually I dont need to specify the full path. r'data\noktalar.sdb' is enough.